# Accessing tasks progress from the Driver in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to do some actions at the `Driver` side in Spark while an application is running. The `Driver` needs to know the tasks progress before making any decision. I know that tasks progress can be accessed within each `executor` or `task` from `RecordReader` class by calling `getProgress()`.

The question is, how can I let the `Driver` call or have an access to `getProgress()` method of each task? I thought about using `broadcast` variables, but I don't know how the `Driver` would distinguish between different tasks.

Note that I am not looking for results displayed in Spark UI.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you mean the progress of an individual task? Or the progress of a job/stage? For the later, you can see how Zeppelin Notebook makes the progress bar : https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/spark/spark-scala-parent/src/main/scala/org/apache/zeppelin/spark/JobProgressUtil.scala

Comment: The progress of an individual task

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to send the progress from each Executor thread to a listening thread in the Driver. This has to be a seperate thread as the main thread is blocked while the action is in progress.